# Add Custom Template Html in Component Selector

Tags: angular

> **Is there a way to add custom template html inside a component-selector?**

I have a component `AppToolbarComponent` with selector `<app-toolbar>` which has a blank template. I would like to use this component on two different components, but with template defined while using the component. For example:

On **`page-one.component.html`:**

```
<app-toolbar>
    <button (click)="onClickOne()">Button in Component One</button>
</app-toolbar>
```

... and on **`page-two.component.html`:**

```
<app-toolbar>
    <button (click)="onClickTwo()">Button in Component Two</button>
</app-toolbar>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using `<ng-content>`?

Comment: @pixelbits superb! Didn't know about that, I was trying with `<ng-template>`. Works like a charm (Y) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on the comment by **`@pixelbits`**, here is an answer:

In `<app-toolbar>`, add `<ng-content>` in the component template. Here is an example:

```
<div>Some Content</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Now, anything added inside the `<app-toolbar>` selector will be rendered inside the `<ng-content>`. For example:

```
<app-toolbar>
    <!-- The following content will render inside <ng-content> 
         in the app-toolbar component -->
    <button (click)="onClickOne()">Button in Component One</button>
</app-toolbar>
```

Here is a link to [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehgtqx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).